# Utf-8 option makes ALT key to insert accented characters in Vim. How to disable it?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, vim, gvim, unicode

I put the following lines to my _vimrc file in GVim on Windows XP:

```
set encoding=utf-8
set fileencodings=ucs-bom,utf-8
```

Then, ALT key changed its behavior in insert mode. Now, ALT key inserts accented characters when pressed with a letter key.

I have several mappings for ALT key in insert mode. But I need to use utf-8 as well. How can I enable utf-8 without changing the behavior of ALT key?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found an acceptable solution:

I put my existing ALT key mappings after utf-8 settings. So my mappings are not broken.

Comment: You can mark your own answer as accepted, so people searching for this same question would know it already has a solution before even entering in this thread.